# How to handle ? operator in Rust in cases where function return type can't be Result<T, E>

Tags: rust

I was reading [THE BOOK](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) about the ? operator and wanted to use it in a function which doesn't have a `Result<T, E>` type. Below mentioned part was written in it:

> This error points out that we’re only allowed to use the `?` operator in a function that returns `Result`, `Option`, or another type that implements `FromResidual`.
>
> To fix the error, you have two choices. One choice is to change the return type of your function to be compatible with the value you’re using the `?` operator on as long as you have no restrictions preventing that. The other technique is to use a match or one of the `Result<T, E>` methods to handle the `Result<T, E>` in whatever way is appropriate.

I saw no implementation of this and simply writing match before the statement with ? doesn't work.
How do I catch that error and use it to return some other dependent value for my function.

My code looked something like this (obv. it didn't run)... I'm not really interested in other way to achieve the same functionality, instead I'm asking if it's possible to use this particular operator with this specific config.

```
fn error_handling() -> String{

    //the ? operator (replaces the try macro)
    //Shorthand, passes the Ok() value out while returns the Err() value.
    //Also can pass the Some() value from Option<T> and return None value.
    //
    //If function doesn't have the return type as Result<T, E> then either extract
    //the value out of Ok with a match statement or change the Return type in code.


    let mut result = String::new();

    let file_return = match fs::File::open("something.txt")? {
        Ok(data) => data.read_to_string(&mut result),
        Err(_) => &result.clear()
    }
    result
}
```

Comment: It's... not really clear what you're asking here? Why are you using `?` *along with* a `match`? You should use one or the other, not both.

Comment: Also it's not clear why you want to use `?` *at all*, since you don't return the error to callers and return the allocated string whether you successfully read the file in or not. Note that this is arguably poor design: now callers have to check if the string is empty or not instead of just handling the error case.

Comment: well it was written in 'The book' that there was someway to do something with the error before returning it.... that doesn't seem to be the case apparently

Comment: The book does not combine `?` with a `match` expression, and I just followed your link to double-check. Also, like many tutorials, the book moves from simple and easy to grok to more complicated but also covers all the bases, so don't hold that against it :)

Comment: Ohh i just understood what it said... it's saying that instead of using ? operator, handle it with the match clause. Not mix them together or anything... Thank you for explaining, also sorry for the trouble!

Comment: No worries, glad you got squared away

Comment: return a result too, almost all function should return a Result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I catch that error and use it to return some other dependent value for my function.

Just remove the `?`. `expr?` is essentially just this:

```rust
match expr {
    Ok(v) => v,
    Err(e) => return Err(e)
}
```

It performs an "immediate return" of an error if there's one, and otherwise lets you use the unwrapped value. So the type of

```
fs::File::open("something.txt")?
```

is `File`, not `Result<File, ...>`. Therefore the match is not valid anymore.

Incidentally, the `match` <strike>you're writing here</strike> you originally wrote exists in the standard library, it's called [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), so you can pretty much just write

```
fs::File::new("something.txt").expect("something bad happened")
```

The new version also has a built-in shortcut (kinda): [`std::fs::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_to_string.html).

```rust
read_to_string("something.txt").unwrap_or_else(String::new)
```

should be equivalent to the code you wrote.

Comment: ohh... right... I'm such an idiot... Anyways isn't it possible to use ? operator with functions that don't have Result<T, E> as return type?

Comment: `?` is also compatible with `Option` and the somewhat rare [`ControlFlow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.ControlFlow.html). The actual desugaring is a bit more complicated than what I wrote and is really supported by [the `Try` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html), so by looking at implementers you can see what `?` is compatible with. It's a nightly trait so currently you can't implement it yourself (it's only for the developers of the standard library).

Comment: Ahh i see... I got it, so the type of that 'fs::File::open("something.txt")' was File. Got it, thanks, also thanks for the additional info

Comment: Do you often have to use this operator or have you seen this in mainstream code? I was thinking of avoiding learning it... just knowing what it does @Masklinn

Comment: It's super common, code not really being able to handle an error and needing to just chuck it to the caller is a normal occurrence, and `?` allows doing that easily. Even more so because it also works with `Option` which is kinda the same.

Comment: Doesn't mean you have to force yourself to use it mind, you might dislike it (I know some folks find it too discrete / not visible enough), or you might want to avoid it until it "clicks".

Comment: It's so common that it's basically the only macro that ever got into having its own syntax, at language level! Besides, it's extremely convenient so when purposely avoiding it seems counterproductive.